# AWS Cognito Logout in Blazor Server 8.0?

Tags: amazon-web-services, blazor, amazon-cognito, blazor-server-side

Have any one tested AWS Cognito Service with Blazor Server 8.0 ? I have implemented the login functionality. It is working fine. But not working logout.

I have done similar to this approach.

https://chandradev819.in/2020/01/18/aws-cognito-service-in-asp-net-core-3-1-application/

could you please share the code snippets for logout?

I have created my login display component like this

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <b> Hello, @context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "cognito:username")?.Value! </b>
        <a href="/Logoutpage">Log out</a>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="/">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

I have also configure the AWS Cognito logout URL like this

[image]

I have tried to configure all required setting on AWS Cognito